# use of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in HTTP Post method

Tags: http, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

What is the meaning of

ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
  in HTTP Post method..??

my code is

```
         Uri url = new Uri(" http://blah/blah/blah...json");

         HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

         webRequest.Method = "POST";

         webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been using ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in particular project. What I know is, it is the scheme that is used, so the POST parameters you are sending to the server are in the form-urlencoded. For example, if you send the parameter key-value like below:
`name=Agung
        id=121`

then, when you send the request, the POST body will be like encoded to be like this:
        `name=Agung&id=121`

When you are setting ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", then the server will know how to parse the Body parameter you are sending.

Hope it will help

Comment: thanks..for the reply.I am sending a JSON string to the server  so, what will be my content type??  will it be                          webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";    or I should use webRequest.Accept = "application/json ";

Comment: @Jrsahoo if you want to send pure JSON, you should set `webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";`
`webRequest.Accept = "application/json ";` is used if you want to limit the server to give you the response in json.
BTW, if you think my answer does give you the right answer, then you should mark it to be right anwer :)

Comment: yeah your comment really helped me to solve my problem..thanks frnd:)

Answer (score -1):

This is used for Security purpose.

you can get more help [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, only the 'URL encoded' part.